default type arguments doesn't check object property names
I want to create a HiddenField type to ensure an object has both value and hiddenValue properties. However, even though I've provided default type arguments, I'm not getting an error when I pass an object missing the hiddenValue property. Why is this happening? Is this a bug?
type HiddenField = {
  value: string,
  hiddenValue: string
};

function submitForm<T = HiddenField>(fields: T[]) {
  fields.forEach((field, _) => {
    console.log(field)
  });  
}

// can run this function without errors and warnings
submitForm([
  {
    value: 'Taro'
  },
  {
    value: 'YAMADA'
  },
])

packages
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}

Node
% node -v
v23.2.0
% npm -v
10.9.0


A default is not a constraint.  If you change it to a constraint then presumably it does what you want as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so then I'll find a suitable duplicate or write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

I thins default is constraint. please check this link

Okay. I understand this.

The properties of HiddenField are already required.


• "Default types for a type parameter must satisfy the constraint for the type parameter, if it exists" means if you have <T extends U = V> then V must satisfy U. You can't have <T extends string = 0> for example. It does not mean that V constrains T in any way. Which you yourself have demonstrated with your example. If defaults were constraints then why is your default not constraining anything? Does it make sense now? • If you understand that the properties of HiddenField are already required then please [edit] the question not to mention Required.

@jcalz What default argument type mean? It doesn't make sense.

I've just updated.

• The documentation linked above says what default type arguments mean. If you call a generic function and inference fails then it falls back to the default, as shown in this playground link. But you don't want a default at all in your code, so it's less important that you understand defaults than that you understand constraints. So, shall I write an answer? Or is something still not connecting?

still not connecting and sorry for about my link is mistake. this is correct link. If I don't provider any arguments, default types is available but typescript doesn't check any errors.

"When specifying type arguments...unspecified type parameters will resolve to their default types." But you haven't specified them. When you call a generic function, it infers the type arguments unless you manually specify them like submitForm<XXX>([]) where XXX is the manually specified argument. Unfortunately, submitForm<>([]) is syntactically invalid, so there's no way to manually specify zero arguments and have it fall back to the default. But again, you don't want a default here. You want a constraint. This feels like a major digression. What can we do from here?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I really would prefer not to chat, I'm just trying to get this question answered. I will recap: there is no bug in TS shown here. Default type arguments do not constrain anything; inference will happen. If you want a constraint, you should use one, as shown in this playground. If you don't want a constraint, please [edit] the question to describe the precise behavior you're looking for.  Do you not want inference at all? Do you want to force people to always specify the type argument unless they want it to be RequiredHiddenField? etc. How shall we proceed?

You didn't put any type specifiers in the argument you want to type.
adjust function too add HiddenField instead of T
function submitForm<T = RequiredHiddenField>(fields: HiddenField[])

